# What happens when a script tag is removed using jQuery's remove method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script abc.js, which has an event handler for a button as follows:

```
$("button").on("click", function(e){
     $("script[src='abc.js']").remove();
});
```

what happens when the remove on the executing script is called? Will the script be unloaded, or will it stop executing? And what happens when the script is removed from other script file?

Comment: `Will the script be unloaded, or will it stop executing?` Nope, since script tag is just a way to load the script and JS engine doesn't check the presence of script tag before executing a statement.

Comment: would cause in error.....

Comment: `$("<script src='abc.js'></script>").remove();` does not remove an  executing script tag, it creates a new `<script>` tag with the `abc.js` as `src`, but this tag was never added to the DOM, so `remove()` does not have an effect anyway.

Comment: Ok, so I have edited selector passed to jQuery in my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Will the script be unloaded, or will it stop executing?

Nope, since script tag is just a way to load the script and **JS** engine doesn't check/validate the presence of script tag before executing a statement.

So, presence of `script` tag is not relevant once the script has been loaded to the session.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have removed the script file the handlers on it will not be called as the function will no longer exist .

Comment: Removing a `script` tag does not have any effect on the already loaded and evaluated script. The `script` tag is only initially needed to trigger the script load/evaluation, after that the presence of the script tag is not relevant anymore.